# Loading WAV and MP3 files with LWJGL 3?

Tags: assets, audio, loading, lwjgl3, format

Whenever I research audio in LWJGL 3, they always use STB which can only load Ogg files. All of my audio files are in either WAV or MP3 format, and it would be annoying to have to convert all of them. Is there some other library or method I can use that would allow me to load these file formats?

Answer (score 0):

In LWJGL2 there was a loader class called `org.lwjgl.util.WaveData`, used for **.wav* files, that is missing in LWJGL3. You can simply download the source of this class from [the legacy LWJGL website](https://legacy.lwjgl.org/) and add it to your project. Replace `org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.log()` with `System.out.println()` in the source since `LWJGLUtil` does not exist in LWJGL3.

Also, if you are on JDK9 or later, you have to download three source files from the package `com.sun.media.sound` in JDK8 and put them into your project. The package needs to be renamed or you will get a loading error otherwise, since that package still exists in the current JDKs but is hidden.

Such classes are:

- `com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader`.
- `com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileFormat`.
- `com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader`.

Then you can write:

```
WaveData data = WaveData.create(url);
AL10.alBufferData(bufferHandle, data.format, data.data, data.samplerate);
```